# Why calling btmgmt conn-info on a connected device returns with: status 0x02 (Not Connected)

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Im trying to read the RSSI values of a connected BLE device using btmgmt rust library, and always getting `127`.

```rust
    pub fn get_rssi(&self) -> Result<i8, Box<std::error::Error>> {
        let btmgmt = btmgmt::BTMgmt::new()?;
        let address = btmgmt::address::Address::from_string(
            self.addr.as_str(),
            btmgmt::address::AddressType::LeRandom,
        )
        .ok_or("invalid address")?;

        let ci = btmgmt.get_connection_info(u16::from(self.adapter_id), &address)?;

        Ok(ci.rssi)
    }
```

I know for sure that the device is connected, and had services resolved, here's `bluetoothctl` output:

```bash
Device DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F (random)
    Name: Device_name
    Alias: Device_name
    Paired: no
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes #<------------------------------- Connecter yey 
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Vendor specific           (********-****-****-****-************)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    RSSI: -33 #<------------------------------------ We even have RSSI here.
    AdvertisingFlags:
```

I've tryied to call btmgmt using cli, yet it complains that the devices is not connected:

```bash
$ sudo btmgmt conn-info DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F                                  
Get Conn Info for DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F (BR/EDR) failed. status 0x02 (Not Connected)
```

Just for sanity check, I've compared to my connected Bose QC3's (Also BLE device) output:

```bash
$ sudo btmgmt conn-info 4C:87:5D:0C:B5:FC                                 
Connection Information for 4C:87:5D:0C:B5:FC (BR/EDR)
    RSSI 0  TX power -3 maximum TX power 12
```

1. What am I missing?
2. Why `btmgmt` cant get connection info, while it seems everything is resolved as expected by the output of `bluetoothctl`?

Bluez  - 5.53
Kernel - 5.15.0-83-generic

Comment: At least for the cmd tool: try pass `-t 1` for BLE public address and `-t 2` for BLE random address. Otherwise it defaults to Bluetooth Classic.

Comment: Thanks @Emil, tryied your suggestion, no success there"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all @Emil was right, thanks!

If I failed to get `conn-info` at first because I called:

```bash
sudo btmgmt -t 2 conn-info DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F
```

But After reading [this](https://github.com/kismetwireless/bluez-basic-monitor/blob/cd48b2d29aef80719f485414e4221d74fb875b25/mgmt-api.txt#L848C2-L848C2).
The `-t 2` flag location is imported:

```bash
$ sudo btmgmt conn-info -t 2 DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F
Connection Information for DA:A4:58:46:AE:9F (LE Random)
    RSSI -48    TX power 7  maximum TX power 7 <------------- Got result!
```